# How do I backup my Facebook photos and save them to Dropbox and OneDrive?

Tags: facebook, backup, photos

I have lots of photos on Facebook and other photos which my friends tagged / posted on my Facebook wall. I need to back up them and save them to Dropbox and One Drive. What app or tool can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a phone, you can use FBAB to backup your facebook photos.
[Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.piksalstudio.fbabpro&hl=en) , [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/vn/app/fbab-photo-album-backup-for/id1031119839?mt=8)

Answer (score 0):

Login to your Facebook account on your computer. Go to setting>General. There will be a link "Download a copy of your Facebook Data" click it and it will ask for confirmation. You will get a backup of your data on your provided email.